# React increment state value when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a short quiz in react. Each question will have four options, and each option will be associated with a possible outcome at the end. The way I'm keeping track of the options chosen is to keep a tally in my state. See my code below for clarification.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      collaborator: 0,
      pilot: 0,
      producer: 0,
      harmonizer: 0,
      answers: [
        {answer: 'Team building', archetype: 'collaborator'},
        {answer: 'Directing strategy', archetype: 'pilot'},
        {answer: 'Driving task completion', archetype: 'producer'},
        {answer: 'Ensuring long term stability and quality of work', 
         archetype: 'harmonizer'}
      ]
    }
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onSelect(e) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case 'collaborator':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {collaborator: prevState.collaborator ++}
        });
        break;
      case 'pilot':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {pilot: prevState.pilot ++}
        });
        break;
      case 'producer':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {producer: prevState.producer ++}
        });
        break;
      case 'harmonizer':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {harmonizer: prevState.harmonizer ++}
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Form answers={this.state.answers} onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's the component that's my Form component, which is receiving props from App right now.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { RadioGroup, RadioButton } from 'react-radio-buttons';

function Form (props) {
    return (
        <RadioGroup onSelect={props.onSelect}>
            {
                props.answers.map(answer => 
                    <RadioButton key={answer.answer} value={answer.archetype}>
                        {answer.answer}
                    </RadioButton>
                )
            }
        </RadioGroup>
    )
}

Form.propTypes = {
  answers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Form;
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run the app in my browser and look at the state in my dev tools, clicking an option doesn't seem to update the state. I'm guessing the problem is in my `onSelect` function within `App`? I've done a little digging but can't seem to find the solution on my own. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got couple of issues here:

1. The `RadioGroup` [accepts `onChange`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-radio-buttons#usage) and **not** `onSelect`.

   ```
   <RadioGroup onChange={props.onSelect}>
   ```
2. It will return the `value` and **not** the `event`

   ```
   onSelect(value) {
       switch (value) {
         case 'collaborator':
           this.setState(prevState => {
             return { collaborator: prevState.collaborator + 1 }
           });
           break;
   ```
3. You are mutating the state directly with this line:

   ```
   return { collaborator: prevState.collaborator++ }
   ```

   Change it to this:

   ```
    return { collaborator: prevState.collaborator + 1 }
   ```